# MySQL Trigger For update value after insert

Tags: mysql, triggers

```
create table Test1
(
WRO varchar(10),
Test_No varchar(10),
TestDate datetime
);

insert into Test1(WRO,TestDate) values('T0001',now());
create table Test2
(
WRO varchar(10),
Test_No varchar(10),
Test2Date datetime,
TestAmount varchar(10)
);
```

I have to update on `Test1` `Test_No` after insert on `Test2` table `Test_No` both have
common field `WRO`.

Comment: CREATE TRIGGER testref AFTER INSERT ON Test2 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN UPDATE test2 SET Test_No = NEW.Test_No WHERE WRO = NEW.WRO; END; |

Comment: @Prajapathi- You need to update test1 after insert on test2 right?

Comment: @haresh what was the error you were faced on your trigger statement?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following,

```
delimiter |    

CREATE TRIGGER after_insert AFTER INSERT ON Test_2
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    UPDATE Test_1 SET Test_1.Test_No = Test_2.Test_No WHERE <YOUR CONDITION>
END;

|
```

make sure you edit WHERE to match your condition

you may also want to consult [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html) to get better understanding on triggers

Comment: i got an error like
 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ON Test_1 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN UPDATE Test2 SET Test2.Test_No = Test1.Test_No WH' at line 1

Comment: I forgot to add BEFORE INSERT, check the answer now

Comment: new error 
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'END' at line 1

Comment: maybe you need to change delimiter to something else than ";"

Comment: @m1k3y02 Just FYI ,trigger should be for after insert and also on test_1 when test_2 is inserted , update should be done on test_1 based on wro

Comment: @m1k3y02 i hope `;` this should be at the end of where clause.

Answer (score 0):

```
delimiter |
CREATE
    TRIGGER trigger1 
     AFTER INSERT ON test2
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
     UPDATE test1 SET test1.Test_No=new.Test_no where test1.WRO=new.WRO;    
    END;
    |
```